# Not able to access array via key but via loop its possible

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a JSON array (userprofile) over here which contains details such as Language, name etc and I can console.log it successfully and I am fetching this via an API. The location.state.id is something which I am passing from the previous page.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://1xxxxxxx',{
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body:JSON.stringify({
        Action : "getPrifles",
        UserID : location.state.id,
      })
    })
       .then((res) => res.json())
       .then((json) => {
          setUserProfile(json.User)
          
      })
       .catch((err) => {
         console.log(err.message);
       });
  }, []);
```

[image]

However, when I tried to access the langauges, it gives a detail.js:86 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

```
at Detail (detail.js:86

console.log(userprofile[0].Lname)
```

When I do it via a loop instead, this works and I can output the value of Lname. The thing is that there is only one key (0) inside my object

```
  for (var key in userprofile) {
    console.log(key) ==> This gives 0
    console.log(userprofile[key]. Lname) ==> This gives the name Paul which is correct

  }
```

Am I doing something wrong because there is only one key (which is zero) and I dont understand why I cannot access the object via 0.

Comment: I think you need to `JSON.parse(result)` it

Comment: How are you doing the API call?

Comment: You should remove the irrelevant code and post the actual json you are having issue with.  Also [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You need to add the complete code causing error

Comment: Hi I managed to resolved it based on the answer below. Thanks all

Comment: Hi all, thanks. I managed to resolve the problem. It was indirectly caused by the fetch issue so I wasnt sure of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

fetch is asynchronous.

So on initial render `userprofile[0]` is undefined. So you get the error, when you try to access a property of that.

The loop works, because you just don't loop if there is nothing to loop over.

Once fetch is finished executing, you rerender (since state changes) ... in the example with the direct accessing this won't happen, since the Error blocks. The loop works, since no Error was thrown on initial render, so now on rerender (with userprofile[0] now defined) the loop works as expected.